# How to add a dbo.Aspnetroles through a viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-core

So, I'm trying to add a client to the ASP.NET authentication tables from a `ViewModel`, but I can't put the actual role of the person I'm creating, the code I'm using now for the creation is:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using CakeShop.Core.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CakeShop.Core.ViewModel
{
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {

        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;
        IConfiguration configuration;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

 if (!context.Users.Any())
            {
                usr = new IdentityUser
                {
                    Email = userEmail,
                    UserName = userName
                };
                userManager.CreateAsync(usr, password);
            }

            if (!context.UserRoles.Any())
            {
                roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

            }
            if (usr == null)
            {
                usr = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(userEmail).Result;
            }
            if (!userManager.IsInRoleAsync(usr, "Admin").Result)
            {
                userManager.AddToRoleAsync(usr, "Admin");
            }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now I tried various methods but none worked can anybody help me?

Comment: Could you provide what actual method you try no matter work or not?

Comment: i tried doing that